# Logic Simplification using boolean laws problem

Tags: digital-logic, boolean-algebra

I am new to this, I am stuck on simplifying this logic equation. Any help would be great, thank you.

The equation is:

$$
   Y = \bar{A}\bar{B}\bar{D} + ABD +  \bar{A}\bar{C}\bar{D} + ACD + BCD
$$

Comment: We can at the very least expect you to crop and properly rotate a photo. Or actually, **I** do expect you to *type* down your equation instead of photographing it.

Comment: Anyway, this question should be closed as "too broad" because it doesn't even show any attempt and doesn't ask a specific question.

Comment: http://www.rfwireless-world.com/Terminology/DeMorgan-theorem-with-example.html

Comment: Newbie to these things tried various things but ain't got nothing.

Comment: @abhishekgidde then write down what you've tried. Explain why you didn't get any further. Ask a *precise* question that doesn't read "do and explain my homework to me".

Comment: First of all I tried using de Morgan's law where ~A~B~D can be written as ~(A+B+D) did the same with ~A~C~D and also did write ABD as ~(~A+~B+~D) and same with ACD but can't go any further Thank You @MarcusMüller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Y =  ~A~B~D + ABD + ~A~C~D + ACD + BCD

Let's see what the Karnaugh map says, just so I know the goal and also so I can test if the equation given is minimal.

```
 Y=   BA
      00 01 11 10
DC 00  1  0  0  1
   01  1  0  0  0
   11  0  1  1  1
   10  0  0  1  0
```

So the equation given is already minimal. However, there's 3 of them that overlap at DCBA and 2 at ~D~C~B~A.

That means that I should be able to factorize a little bit.

So we got this:
Y =  ~A~B~D + ABD + ~A~C~D + ACD + BCD

Y =  ~B~A~D  + ~C~A~D + ABD + ACD + BCD

Y =  (~B+~C)~A~D + (AB + AC + BC)D

Y =  (~B+~C)~A~D + (AB + (A + B)C)D

And I doubt you can factorize it further than that.

Comment: Thank You for your efforts but that won't reduce the number of gates we use so I guess that's the minimum we can do. Thank You

Comment: Well... If you are using 2-input AND gates, then it will be fewer gates. Oh well.
If you think this answer is the right one, mark it.

Comment: yes i have and the equation i posted is derived from a K-Map.

Comment: If you derived it from a K-Map then you should know that it's pretty much done ;p Oh well.

Comment: and btw you didn't consider the whole equation.

Comment: I didn't? What did I miss?

Comment: you missed the ~A~B~D+ABD part but well I posted this here to check If there can be any further simplification anyways Thank You so much.

Comment: I assume that it's better now :p

Comment: Thank You (This bracket stuff just to bypass the min char limit of a comment) @HarrySvensson